# Need help in proving an inclusion between some subspaces of operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

Let $V$ be a closed subspace of $B(H,K)$ such that $xy^*z \in V$ for all $x,y,z \in V$. Let $I$ be an ideal $(IV^*V+VV^*I \subset I)$ of $V$. Let $C(I)$ denote the $C^{\ast}$-algebra generated by $II^{\ast}$. In a paper the following inclusion is stated without proof:

> $VI^{\ast} \subset C(I)$

I don’t see how this can be true, since $C(I)$ is generated by $II^{\ast}$ therefore how could $VI^*$ be included inside $C(I)$?